# According to the spec, is const required with auto for const references?

Tags: c++, c++11

**EDIT** I missed an important detail, the map is `const`. The example has been updated.

Consider

```
const std::map<int, int> ints;
auto& it = ints.find(0);
```

Reviewing both the C++ (working draft) specification, as well as Stroustrup's "The C++ Programming Language, FOURTH EDITION", I cannot determine if `const` is required (I do believe decorating the type explicitly with `const` is better stylistically, but such is not my question). Visual Studio 2013 compiles it fine, deducing `const`.

I understand that a naked `auto` (i.e. no decorations such as `const` nor `&`) will deduce a non-const, non-reference type.

In every example in Stroupstrup's book, he uses `const auto&` and never `auto&` for such scenarios. **edit** But he doesn't speak to the option/need of using `const`, they are just examples of `auto`.

gcc 4.9.1 fails to compile it, as does xcode for mac:
`error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ...`

Are these compiler choices? Does the specification speak either way about this?

Thanks.

Comment: `auto` uses template argument deduction rules, and what it deduces is completely specified by the standard. `auto &` will not deduce a const-qualified type unless you attempt to bind it to a const-qualified object.

Comment: Oh goodness this is a _completely_ different question now. Please take more care in the future.

Comment: I still don't understand ... why is the `map` being `const` or not important here? That affects the return type of `map::find`, it'll return `map::const_iterator` if the `map` is `const`, and `map::iterator` otherwise, **by value** in both cases. So the code above will fail to compile, regardless of the const-ness of the `map` because you're attempting to bind an rvalue to a non-const lvalue reference. VS compiles it because of a non-standard extension; it'll tell you as much if you compile with `/W4`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this behaviour is entirely standard-mandated:

> `[C++11: 7.1.6.4/5]:` A program that uses `auto` in a context not explicitly allowed in this section is ill-formed.
>
> `[C++11: 7.1.6.4/6]:` Once the type of a *declarator-id* has been determined according to 8.3, the type of the declared variable using the *declarator-id* is determined from the type of its initializer using the rules for template argument deduction. Let `T` be the type that has been determined for a variable identifier d. Obtain `P` from `T` by replacing the occurrences of auto with either a new invented type template parameter `U` or, if the initializer is a *braced-init-list* (8.5.4), with `std::initializer_list<U>`. **The type deduced for the variable `d` is then the deduced `A` determined using the rules of template argument deduction from a function call (14.8.2.1), where `P` is a function template parameter type and the initializer for `d` is the corresponding argument. If the deduction fails, the declaration is ill-formed.**
>
> `[C++11: 14.8.2.1/3]:` **If `P` is a cv-qualified type, the top level cv-qualifiers of `P`’s type are ignored for type deduction. If `P` is a reference type, the type referred to by `P` is used for type deduction.** If `P` is an rvalue reference to a cv-unqualified template parameter and the argument is an lvalue, the type “lvalue reference to `A`” is used in place of `A` for type deduction.

You've added the `&` (which would have been necessary even if `std::map<int, int>::find const` were to return a reference, which it doesn't by the way); now add the `const` (required per the above)!

Answer (score 0):

The cause of your error is attempting to bind a temporary object to an lvalue reference to non-const.

Consider this example:

```
      int  i = 42;
const int ci = 42;

auto& a =  i; // type of  i is       int, value category of  i is lvalue -- OK
auto& b = ci; // type of ci is const int, value category of ci is lvalue -- OK
auto& c = 42; // type of 42 is       int, value category of 42 is rvalue -- error
```

`auto` will deduce the type of the initializing expression according to template arugment deduction rules, so `a` is an `int&` and b is a `const int&`.

But if the initializing expression is a non-const rvalue, like a literal `42`, or `ints.find(0)`, `auto` will deduce a non-const type, so `c` is an `int&` (lvalue reference to non-const) which will not bind to an rvalue.

```
auto&& d =  i; // d is       int&  -- OK
auto&& e = ci; // e is const int&  -- OK
auto&& f = 42; // f is       int&& -- OK
```

`auto&&` is a forwarding reference which will deduce both the cv-qualification (constness) and value category of its initializing expression.